# Looping an Equation to Fill a Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a loop that is working as intended, but I want to place each individual iteration of the loop  into a data frame

```
def stock_growth(p, r, n, t):
    t = 1
    for t in range(1,31):
        FV = p * (((1+r/n)**(t*n)-1)/r/n)    
    return FV
```

I have my empty data frame and I am defining the function as FV

```
FV2 = pd.Dataframe()
FV = stock_growth(p, r, n, t)
```

I know I'm not calling the variables into FV2. I'm looping this 30 times and I want each of those 30 times to end up in either a table or list so that I can graph it.

Comment: Why do you need dataframe if you want only to graph the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can append all values into a list inside a loop and then return the entire list to lst_val list.

```
def stock_growth(p, r, n, t):
    result = []
    for t in range(1,31):
        FV = p * (((1+r/n)**(t*n)-1)/r/n)   
        result.append(FV)
    return result

lst_val = stock_growth(p, r, n, t) 
# you can use lst_val to draw
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lst_val = stock_growth(4,3, -2,-55) 

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('stock_growth')
plt.plot(lst_val)
plt.show()
```

[image]